# Flutter: Conditional statement for my IconButton is not working

Tags: flutter, android-layout, iconbutton

I only want my iconButton to show if there is more info on my row.
What is the correct way to code this? My if has red error mark on it.

```
                  if(item.info != ""){
                          child: IconButton(
                          icon:
                          const Icon(Icons.info_outline_rounded),
                               onPressed: () {
                      
                                 Navigator.push(
                                   context,
                                   MaterialPageRoute(
                                   builder: (context) => const Page2()));
                               }, //onPressed
                          ), //IconButton
                 }, //end if statement
     ), //Center
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Center(
  child: item.info != ""
      ? IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.info_outline_rounded),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Page2()));
          }, //onPressed
        )
      : Container(),
)
```

or with Visibility widget

```
Visibility(
    visible: item.info != "",
    child: IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.info_outline_rounded),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Page2()));
      }, //onPressed
    ))
```

Comment: Thanks Sartaj, I learned something new -> Visibility widget.

Answer (score 1):

And if you do not want to add unnecessary widget while condition is false. You can try this

```
if (item.info != "")
              Center(
                  child: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.info_outline_rounded),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Page2()));
                }, //onPressed
              )),
```

If condition will false then it will not render any widget.